# Do C#10’s readonly record structs guarantee the same size and alignment of fields as the explicit implementation?

Tags: c#, structlayout, c#-10.0

I do stuff where having contiguous data is required. Now with C# 10, we can do `public readonly record struct`.

I like having the automatic ToString feature that records have, among others, so having that done for me is nice.

As such, are the following equivalent?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public readonly struct MyVector
{
    public readonly float X;
    public readonly float Y;
    public readonly float Z;

    public MyVector(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

versus the nicely condensed C# 10 version

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public readonly record struct MyVectorRecord(float X, float Y, float Z)
{
}
```

Or are there any landmines I'm going to accidentally step on doing this? By which I mean are there any things being done under the hood by `record` that make what I've written above not do what I want with respect to contiguous packing? I can't have the record insert padding, spacing, or do anything weird.

I am not using a vector class with record structs and was using this for purposes of illustration. You can ignore things like "floating point equality comparisons" since I am only interested in whether I can pass this off to a library that is expecting a contiguous sequence of X/Y/Z's.

Comment: It's still a struct. Records aren't a new kind of type, they're new behavior over the existing types. In fact, without the `readonly` keyword a `record struct` is mutable, just like any other `struct`

Comment: PS: Why not use a `Vector3` which would allow you to use SIMD operations?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is there a Vector3 for doubles? There are some nice convenient features like having access to add properties as needed, or constructor overloading like doing `Vec3 v = (1, 2, 3);`. There is one worry I have which is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/simd) saying "In general the performance benefit of using SIMD varies depending on the specific scenario, and in some cases it can even perform worse than simpler non-SIMD equivalent code." Not saying these are great reasons, and I'm more than open to be convinced of changing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`record` isn't a new type, it's specific behavior applied to reference and now value types. The struct remains a struct. You can test this at [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=), to see the code generated by the compiler in each case.

A record uses properties though, not raw fields, so you can only compare structs with properties to record structs. That's the important difference

This struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public readonly struct MyVectorRecord2
{ 
    public float X {get;} 
    public float Y {get;} 
    public float Z {get;}
    
     public MyVectorRecord2(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

produces

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
[IsReadOnly]
public struct MyVectorRecord2
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly float <X>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly float <Y>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly float <Z>k__BackingField;

    public float X
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <X>k__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public float Y
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Y>k__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public float Z
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Z>k__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public MyVectorRecord2(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        <X>k__BackingField = x;
        <Y>k__BackingField = y;
        <Z>k__BackingField = z;
    }
}
```

While the record

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public readonly record struct MyVectorRecord(float X, float Y, float Z)
{
}
```

produces:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
[IsReadOnly]
public struct MyVectorRecord : IEquatable<MyVectorRecord>
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly float <X>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly float <Y>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private readonly float <Z>k__BackingField;

    public float X
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <X>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        init
        {
            <X>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public float Y
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Y>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        init
        {
            <Y>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public float Z
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Z>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        init
        {
            <Z>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }

    public MyVectorRecord(float X, float Y, float Z)
    {
        <X>k__BackingField = X;
        <Y>k__BackingField = Y;
        <Z>k__BackingField = Z;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("MyVectorRecord");
        stringBuilder.Append(" { ");
        if (PrintMembers(stringBuilder))
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(' ');
        }
        stringBuilder.Append('}');
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Append("X = ");
        builder.Append(X.ToString());
        builder.Append(", Y = ");
        builder.Append(Y.ToString());
        builder.Append(", Z = ");
        builder.Append(Z.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyVectorRecord left, MyVectorRecord right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyVectorRecord left, MyVectorRecord right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (EqualityComparer<float>.Default.GetHashCode(<X>k__BackingField) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<float>.Default.GetHashCode(<Y>k__BackingField)) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<float>.Default.GetHashCode(<Z>k__BackingField);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is MyVectorRecord && Equals((MyVectorRecord)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyVectorRecord other)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<float>.Default.Equals(<X>k__BackingField, other.<X>k__BackingField) && EqualityComparer<float>.Default.Equals(<Y>k__BackingField, other.<Y>k__BackingField) && EqualityComparer<float>.Default.Equals(<Z>k__BackingField, other.<Z>k__BackingField);
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out float X, out float Y, out float Z)
    {
        X = this.X;
        Y = this.Y;
        Z = this.Z;
    }
}
```

Finally, this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public readonly struct MyVector
{
    public readonly float X;
    public readonly float Y;
    public readonly float Z;

    public MyVector(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

Remains unchanged, apart from the `IsReadOnly` attribute.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
[IsReadOnly]
public struct MyVector
{
    public readonly float X;

    public readonly float Y;

    public readonly float Z;

    public MyVector(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

The big difference is between structs with fields and structs with public properties. After that, a `record struct` contains only extra methods compared to a struct with properties.